# Decent Numbers | Help Reduce Time Complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, big-o, time-complexity

[HackerRank Problem Statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-the-beast)

I have to find the largest "decent number" having 'N' digits. A Decent Number has the following properties:

```
=> 3, 5, or both as its digits. No other digit is allowed.
=> Number of times 3 appears is divisible by 5.
=> Number of times 5 appears is divisible by 3.
```

My code works perfect! But I am afraid it is far from efficient:

Input:

```
4 #number of test cases, i.e., the following 4 inputs
1
3
5
11
```

Output:

```
-1
555
33333
55555533333
```

My version of the solution:

```
T = int(input()) #number of test cases

def computePair(N):
    multiplesOf3 = [i for i in range(N+1) if i%3 == 0]
    if multiplesOf3 != [0]: #reversing a [0] results in a 'NoneType'
        multiplesOf3.reverse()
    multiplesOf5 = [i for i in range(N+1) if i%5 == 0]

    for i in multiplesOf3:
        for j in multiplesOf5:
            if (i+j) == N:
                return (i, j)
    return -1

for testCase in range(T):
    N = int(input()) #test case
    result = computePair(N)
    if result == -1:
        print(result) #If no such combination exists return '-1'
    else:
        print('5' * (result[0]) + '3' * (result[1]))
```

I assume my code has a time-complexity of O(n^2); because of the 2 'for' loops. I want this to be more efficient in the order of O(n) - linear.

This is a very generic question: Also, do you have any resources to time-complexity best practices? I suck at it.

Comment: If you duplicated ur question on CodeReview, plz delete this question. IMO, this question purely asks about a better algorithm, which is perfectly on topic.

Answer (score 5):

To solve this problem, we need to make few observations:

- `the largest "decent number" having 'N' digits` is the number that contains the most number of digit 5. It will have the form 5555...3333...
- As `Number of times 5 appears is divisible by 3`, so we have three cases:

  - If N is divided by 3, so there is no digit 3 .
  - If `N % 3 = 1`, so we need to add `a times` digit 3 to the result, and `a % 3 == 1` to make the total number of digit 5 `(N - a)` divisible by 3 , so `a % 3 == 1` and `a % 5 == 0` -> `a = 10`. (Notice that `a` has to be smallest among all valid values). Final result will have `(N - 10)` digits of 5 and `10` digits of 3.
  - Similarly, if `N % 3 = 2`, so we need to add `a times` digit 3 to the result, `a % 3 == 2` and `a % 5 == 0` -> `a = 5`;

With those observations, you can solve this problem in O(1) for each N.

Comment: Obviously, you can just hardcode the special cases when `N<9`.